# How to define a sense of bitter satisfaction (or ironic bitterness) at having resigned over a principle - which was then upheld after you left

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests

Tracey Crouch, UK Sports Minister, resigned because the government delayed a ban on gambling machines. More than a week after her resignation, the government changed its position - and acted upon her earlier insistence. Is there a phrase to encapsulate her situation and sentiment? A sort of inverted schadenfreude...?

Comment: "Vindication" would fit rather well

Answer (score 1):

The phrase **cold comfort** seems apt to describe her state of mind, but doesn't quite capture the ironical nature of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you provided could be worded:

Tracey Crouch, UK Sports Minister, resigned because the government
 delayed a ban on gambling machines. More than a week after her
 resignation, the government changed its position and delivered
 **poetic justice**:  by acting upon her earlier insistence.

**poetic justice**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/146532?redirectedFrom=poetic%20justice#eid29358473)

> (b) (now more generally) the fact of experiencing a fitting or
>   deserved retribution for one's actions; an outcome in which virtue
>   triumphs over vice (often ironically)

When good is rewarded with luck or a happy ending — or doing something bad results in punishment, it's **poetic justice**.

A recent sentence:

> “I thought that was a little bit of **poetic justice**, if you will,”
>   Coach Barry Trotz said, “for all the tough times.” Washington Post Jun
>   1, 2018

Comment: Your opening block quote looks like an uncited quote. If it is a more extensive quote than the OP’s, please cite it. Otherwise, consider formatting it differently - e.g. as a bullet point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "hollow redemption" or if it has to be one word, "martyr"?